# mouseenter wait a bit then display the div item (in seconds?)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to accomplish something where the user hovers over an item and jquery takes over and displays the item (but only after a few seconds).  I've got the following HTML listed:

```
<ul id="ulPersonal">
      <li class="break eTime">
        <p>Manage your time card.</p>
        <div id="dEtime">
          some content
        </div>
       </li>
</ul>
```

The li item is visible, and once you `mouseenter` into it I show the div `dEtime` as shown (here is the jquery):

```
        $('#dEtime').hide();
        $(".eTime").mouseenter(function () {
            $('#dEtime').fadeIn('slow');
        });
```

This works great..when the user hovers over the `li` item the div fades in.  However, I want to wait about 2-3 seconds before this happens.  Meaning allow the user to hover over the li, it should wait and then open only if they are still hovering more then 2 seconds.  If they "un-hover" before those 2 seconds the div should never appear.

I hope that makes sense.  Basically allow hover but only display the div once 2 seconds is up.
Otherwise dont display it.  I've got a lot of div's I need to do this to but was hoping to keep it simple for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) + [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
var id;
$('#dEtime').hide();
$(".eTime").hover(
    function () {
        id = setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dEtime').fadeIn('slow');
        }, 2000)
    },
    function() {
        if (id != null) {
            clearInterval(id);
        }        
        $('#dEtime').fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7r92/1/)

Comment: @oJM86o: added fadeout on mouseleave

Answer (score 1):

Use `.delay()`

```
$('#dEtime').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
```

The add a mouseleave even with a fade out like that :

```
$(".eTime").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#dEtime').stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow')
});
```

Here'S a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r3XJE/2/

Even better would be to use `.hover()` to have a shorter code like this :

```
$('#dEtime').hide();
$(".eTime").hover(function () {
    $('#dEtime').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
},
function(){
    $('#dEtime').stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow')
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r3XJE/1/

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, as soon as I leave the hover it reappears after 2 seconds.

Comment: try this, with a combination of $(".eTime").mouseleave(function () {
    $('#dEtime').hide();
});

Comment: That was because there was no `mouseleave` even, edited my answer, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$('#dEtime').hide();
$(".eTime").mouseenter(function () {
$('#dEtime').delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');
});
$(".eTime").mouseleave(function () {
$('#dEtime').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using setTimeout as sugested by 'Sushanth --', when I made something similar a litle while back. The trick is to save the id this returns and then on mouseleave you run clearTimeout on this id.

I also found that the FadeIn / FadeOut got confused if I stopped them mid-run, stopping at only a few percent opacity instead of fading all the way in or out... I switched to FadeTo that let me set the target opacity level - 0 or 1...